# In Eclipse, how can I ensure the compiled program will be for a certain JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I'm working in Eclipse. How can I ensure two things:

1- Exactly, as far as Eclipse is concerned, what JDK I am using?

2- Exactly for what JRE the compiled program will be suitable, again as far as Eclipse is concerned. Meaning how to ensure for what JRE Eclipse is compiling?

How can I know for sure these two things?

Comment: 1) Set the project's JDK and source level. 2) See 1.

Comment: I don't understand this question very good. Do you want to know what JRE and JDK you are using for your project in Eclipse or what?

Comment: @brano Yes. Assuming I have more than one JRE and JDK installed on my computer, I want to make sure what JDK Eclipse is using for my project, and for what JRE version Eclipse is going to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your Java project > Properties > Java Build Path > select Libraries tab and there you will see what `JRE` is currently used.

To change `JRE`: Select current `JRE` from Java Build Path dialog > Edit > make Alternate JRE selected and then click Installed `JREs` > click Add > Standard VM > click on Directory button and browse for desired `JREs` directory. After adding that `JRE` make sure to check it in Installed `JREs` dialog. Click Ok and then finish.